# write on newline in a text file on each iteration using python

Tags: python, file-io

want to write in newline in each iteration but it does not work out. i read random string using function getUser() and getFriends() from abc.txt. And write  in text file new_file.txt but it writes in first line in each iteration

output:['Larina'] ['Oormi', 'Palky']['Kavia'] ['Chakradhari', 'Chunni']

i need in this format:

['Larina'] ['Oormi', 'Palky']

['Kavia'] ['Chakradhari', 'Chunni']

```
with open("new_file.txt", "wb") as sink:
        for i in range(0,2):
            print>>sink, getUser(),getFriends()
            #print>>sink,("\n")

def getUser():
    with open("abc.txt", "rb") as source:
        lines = [line.rstrip() for line in source]
    random_choice = random.sample(lines, 1)
    source.close()
    return(random_choice);
def getFriends():
    with open("abc.txt", "rb") as source:
        lines = source.read().splitlines()

    random_choice = random.sample(lines, 2)
    source.close()
    return(random_choice);
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Line breaks are added by the `print` statement as they should. Maybe you're using a bad text editor that doesn't recognize `\n` as line breaks and expects `\r\n`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to close `source` because `with` statement does it for you.

Try this code:

```
with open("new_file.txt", "wb") as sink:
        for i in range(0,2):
            sink.write("%s %s\n" % (str(getUser()), str(getFriends())))

def getUser():
    with open("abc.txt", "rb") as source:
        lines = [line.rstrip() for line in source]
    random_choice = random.sample(lines, 1)
    return(random_choice);

def getFriends():
    with open("abc.txt", "rb") as source:
        lines = source.read().splitlines()
    random_choice = random.sample(lines, 2)
    return(random_choice)
```